# parse specific key in json to dataframe column

Tags: json, pandas

How do you parse a specific key to multiple rows and column from a response?

I am getting a response:

```
response = requests.post('https://api.kewords.com/v1/get_keyword_data', data=my_data, headers=my_headers)
```

which returns:

```
{
"data": {
    "heart disease": {
        "vol": 18100,
        "cpc": {
            "currency": "$",
            "value": "2.01"
        },
        "keyword": "keyword planner",
        "competition": 0.21,
        "trend": [
            {
                "month": "January",
                "year": 2022,
                "value": 18100
            },
            {
                "month": "February",
                "year": 2022,
```

However, when I normalize it before I save it to a .csv, it places everything into a single row:

[image]

How do you parse a specific field, like data.heart disease.trend in my example, with separate columns for year and month based on value to a pandas dataframe? Every method from normalizing it to dealing with it as a dict has failed.

my code:

```
my_data = {
    'country': 'us',
    'currency': 'USD',
    'dataSource': 'cli',
    
    f'kw[{keyword}]': ["keywords tool", "keyword planner"]
}
my_headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': ''
}
response = requests.post('https://api.keywords.com/v1/get_keyword_data', data=my_data, headers=my_headers)

#write to json
with open('output.json', 'wb') as outf:
    outf.write(response.content)
    
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('success\n\n', response.content.decode('utf-8'))
else:
    print("An error occurred\n\n", response.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: post the (full or meaningful/completed part)  testable `response` dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
data = json.loads(response.text)

df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data["data"]["heart disease"],
    meta=["vol", "keyword", "competition", "cpc"],
    record_path="trend"
)
df = pd.concat([df.drop(["cpc"], axis=1), df["cpc"].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      month  year  value    vol          keyword competition currency value
0   January  2022  18100  18100  keyword planner        0.21        $  2.01
1  February  2022  20000  18100  keyword planner        0.21        $  2.01
```

Comment: Thanks Jason!  I see, so it was a few things but the key is to really set the record_path and then concat.

Comment: The last line is to handle the dict that the "cpc" holds and to concat it to the rest of the df. Please also mark the issue resolved when you have a chance.